How can i make a class in vue based on a condition from a database
I have multiple div elements with a class based on a special condition. I'm checking this condition once I receive data from a database. The problem is the component is rendered before receiving the data from a database. I've tried to make an async function and use await, but it didn't work. (I'm not very proficient in JS and Vue)
Component:
<v-table v-if="allActions.length != 0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center text-blue" :colspan="lastWeekCount + 1">Недели</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left text-blue">Actions</th>
      <th v-for="week in 15" :key="week" class="text-center text-blue">
        {{ week + firstWeekCount - 1 }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="action in allActions" :key="action">
      <td>{{ action.reason }}</td>
      <td v-for="week in 15" :key="week" class="text-center">
        <div>
          <v-dialog max-width="500">
            <template
              v-slot:activator="{
                props: activatorProps,
              }"
            >
              <div
                v-if="checkActionStatus(week + firstWeekCount - 1, action.id)"
                @click="selectChosenAction(week + firstWeekCount - 1, action.id)"
                v-bind="activatorProps"
                :class="checkActionStatus(week + firstWeekCount - 1, action.id)"
                style="height: 15px; width: 15px"
              ></div>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:default="{ isActive }">
              <v-card title="Change a status">
                <v-card-text>
                  <v-select
                    v-model="chosenAction.status"
                    :items="['OK', 'nOK', 'Empty']"
                    label="Status state"
                    :disabled="isStatus"
                    item-title="name"
                    return-object
                    variant="solo"
                  ></v-select>
                  <div v-if="isStatus" class="text-red-lighten-1">
                    Action is already chosen
                  </div>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn text="Close" @click="isActive.value = false"></v-btn>
                  <v-btn
                    class="ma-2"
                    color="success"
                    variant="flat"
                    v-bind="props"
                    @click="updateChosenAction"
                    >Save</v-btn
                  >
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </template>
          </v-dialog>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</v-table>

function with async await:
const checkActionStatus = async (week, action_id) => {
  try {
    const response = await httpServer.post("selectActionByWeek", { week: week, action: action_id });
    if (response.data[0]) {
      switch (response.data[0].status) {
        case 'Empty':
          return "bg-blue-grey-lighten-3 rounded-circle mx-auto";
        case 'OK':
          return "bg-light-green-accent-3 rounded-circle mx-auto";
        case 'nOK':
          return "bg-amber-lighten-2 rounded-circle mx-auto";
        default:
          return "bg-blue-grey-lighten-3 rounded-circle mx-auto";
      }
    } else {
      return "bg-blue-grey-lighten-3 rounded-circle mx-auto";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return "bg-blue-grey-lighten-3 rounded-circle mx-auto";
  }
};


I think it will work with async await, can you share the code using async await that you have tried?

I added the function with async/await

You can always hide the component until you have a response from the backend (using v-show), then use a v-if to handle the condition.

Also, when using async/await, do not use .then.

@kissu
https://codepen.io/DieHardy/pen/GRLaJvW
I uploaded updated code on codepen, I didn't know that i don't need to use .then, ty. But still it doesn't work.
I always used a variable inside v-if, but in this case I need to use a temp value from returning value.

I mean this is an element inside v-for. And it seems to me that I can't use 1 variable as a temporary value

What are you trying to show me in the Codepen? There is no external call so that doesn't add more value than your code above. Not sure what would be the issue with a v-if but it should work well even if it's temporary. Please update your code above to maybe explain the v-for + v-if issue.

Which v-for is not working here? Also, please update your async/await code by removing the .then. Lastly, rather than using an inline console.log, prefer using a method or better: checking the Vue devtools to inspect the state.

@kissu v-for are working here. I meant I'm not sure that I can use v-if on a returning value from a function because I always used a ref variable.
I updated the code on StackOverflow as my current code.  The issue is the same.
I see responses in my network tab, but the class is empty.

I think it's because: a component is rendered before it gets a value from a function

Btw, did you mean console.log(error) this log?

Not sure what you mean by I meant I'm not sure that I can use v-if on a returning value from a function, but let's try to see by using an example. Should be totally feasible! If you see the responses in your network tab, then you could also display the response data you're receiving. Display it in your template using <pre>{{ response }}</pre>. This might help you visually exactly what you have if you do not like using the Vue devtools. Btw, where are consuming this response? Don't you want to have I dynamic class somewhere in your component?

If a component is rendered before a function, it should not be a big deal. You can have dynamic updates, thanks to the reactivity. At least, I do not see how it would be an issue here for now. For the console.log, you fixed it. As a general rule, console.log is not always the best way to debug things hence why I proposed that you would remove it. So back to your question, what do you have in the response and do you want to have (expected) there?

I think, that I need to explain what I'm trying to achieve and you could tell me how to do it right because my solution can be irrelevant in this case because of a lack of knowledge.
My goal is to make a system of actions, where every action can have different statuses like 'Empty', 'nOK', 'OK'.
From the start, there are no action rows in a database. The status will only be saved in the database if I update it manually.
What I'm trying to achieve is to make different colors for each status.
I do this by calling the function each time an action is generated.

So: 1. action is generated 2 calling a checker function 3 returning a necessary class
I've tried to make a dynamic class like: :class='{color: condition}'.
It worked as this: I created an additional array containing all actions in the database and checked each one against every new action.
Like: 1 action is generated 2 start array with all actions in a db 3 if it has the same week and id set the necessary class. It worked, but if I have 5 rows in a db, one of the action will be green and then it will also print 4 other actions..

I've tried to make a flag to control this, but I couldn't do it. I've tried to set it like {{flag = false}} where flag is a global variable. So.. I decided to make it simpler => make a request each time once action is generated, but as always I have lots of problems with promises..
Sorry for my English. I hope you get the main idea.
As for your second answer:
I used <pre>
and I got
[object Promise]
I'm making a request with parameters such as week and action_id and getting the row from a database with all parameters for the row that was found.

My response: {id: 21, action: 173, week: 15, coef: null, status: 'OK', …} I have a row if it was found; otherwise, it returns undefined. After that I check which row I got if it has a status parameter I check it and return a certain class based on my need. @kissu

Okay, so first off we need to fix [object Promise]. For that, I noticed that you use a method on a v-if and class, which is possible. You will need to call the checkActionStatus function on a lifecycle hook like onMounted or on an event like @click. You cannot call an async HTTP call with arguments like v-if or class just like that. Btw, do you even need to do a call here, can't you have something static as shown here? You could actually have a global theme. Also try your HTTP call with hardcoded arguments for now (week + action).

I did it!! Thank you so much! :) @kissu
First, I've tried to use onMounted, but it's not what I needed. So instead of making a request for each status I made 1 request for all statuses on @click and then just checked this object and compared it with the current action.
The final result: I made a reactive object and put data.response there . I checked your solution how you implemented this kind of logic and did smth like this: :class="setStatus(week, action).

I'm sure my solution is far from perfect, but it's okay in my case in terms of rows in a a database and sequentially elements in object.
But I still wonder how it's implemented in web apps when we have to proceed a huge amount of data. It'll be a bad decision to take 1 million and compare them each time to set a status. Are features like pagination leveraged to handle situations like these?
Btw, do I need to upload my code here after I solved the problem?

Glad it works! I am not sure to still understand the full scope of your issue but there are definitely ways to improve the performance on a lot of different scopes. Don't optimize prematurely if it works well. I'll upload my answer there, you can upvote + accept it so that both of us are happy!

I'm not sure I can vote because of the lack of my reputation

That was a good interaction and the question was decently explained, so that to my upvote you now have enough reputation. Wish you a good day!

I marked your solution as accepted :)
Thanks for the help again and good luck with everything!
@kissu

OP moved his calls to an @click, getting some inspiration on this other answer also helped a bit.
